# pyaudio and pynput: recording while a key is being pressed/held down

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard-events, pyaudio

I am currently trying to make a simple script which records while a key is being pressed. I need to generate some data, so the intention with the script was to prompt the terminal with an sentence, and when the speaker presses a key will the script start recording, at which the speaker reads the sentence. when the sentence has been spoken, and recorded should a key release stop the recording and thus create the audio file..

This is what i currently have:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None

        self.stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                             channels=CHANNELS,
                             rate=RATE,
                             input=True,
                             frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                             stream_callback = self.callback)
        print self.stream.is_active()

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
            self.key_pressed = True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
            self.key_pressed = False

    def callback(self,in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        if self.key_pressed == True:
            return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
        elif self.key_pressed == False:
            return (in_data, pyaudio.paComplete)
        else:
            return (in_data,pyaudio.paAbort)


listener = MyListener()
listener.start()
started = False

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if listener.key_pressed == True and started == False:
        started = True
        listener.stream.start_stream()
        print "start Stream"

    elif listener.key_pressed == False and started == True:
        print "Something coocked"
        listener.stream.stop_stream()
        listener.stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()

        started = False
```

I seem to have problems with the frames keep dropping, and nothing is being recorded.  I made the implementation using a callback function, as I thought maybe the keyboard thread might have been blocking it, so just to be sure.. but nothing seem to be recorded, since I keep getting the `IOerror`... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just rewrite the callback like below.

```
def callback(self,in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    print("callback")
    if self.key_pressed == True:
        #stream_queue.put(in_data)
        print("record")
        frames.append(in_data)
        return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

    elif self.key_pressed == False:
        #stream_queue.put(in_data)
        frames.append(in_data)
        return (in_data, pyaudio.paComplete)

    else:
        print("not record")
        return (in_data,pyaudio.paContinue)
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work at least on Windows, Python 3.5. The biggest problems with the initial code were:
It does a while loop, which blocks pretty much everything,
Frames were not being appended to the frame list. The callback does this now.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import sched
import sys

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    frames.append(in_data)
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None
        self.wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        self.wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        self.wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        self.wf.setframerate(RATE)
    def on_press(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = True
        return True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = False
        return True


listener = MyListener()
listener.start()
started = False
stream = None

def recorder():
    global started, p, stream, frames

    if listener.key_pressed and not started:
        # Start the recording
        try:
            stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                             channels=CHANNELS,
                             rate=RATE,
                             input=True,
                             frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                             stream_callback = callback)
            print("Stream active:", stream.is_active())
            started = True
            print("start Stream")
        except:
            raise

    elif not listener.key_pressed and started:
        print("Stop recording")
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
        listener.wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        listener.wf.close()
        print "You should have a wav file in the current directory"
        sys.exit()
    # Reschedule the recorder function in 100 ms.
    task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())


print "Press and hold the 'r' key to begin recording"
print "Release the 'r' key to end recording"
task = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())
task.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works on my Arch Linux box.
Inspirations: Prior answer in [pyaudio and pynput: recording while a key is being pressed/held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894796/pyaudio-and-pynput-recording-while-a-key-is-being-pressed-held-down), https://gist.github.com/sloria/5693955

```
# Inspirations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894796/pyaudio-and-pynput-recording-while-a-key-is-being-pressed-held-down, https://gist.github.com/sloria/5693955
import logging
import sched
import time
import wave

import pyaudio
from pynput import keyboard


for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s"
)


class KeyPressTriggeredRecorder(object):
    '''Helps record audio during the duration of key-presses.
    Records in mono by default.

    Example usage:
        recorder.KeyPressTriggeredRecorder("test.wav").record()
    '''

    def __init__(self, trigger_key=keyboard.Key.space, channels=1, rate=44100, frames_per_buffer=1024):
        self.trigger_key = trigger_key
        self.key_pressed = False
        self.recording_started = False
        self.recording_stopped = False
        self.channels = channels
        self.rate = rate
        self.frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer
        self.key_listener = keyboard.Listener(self._on_press, self._on_release)
        self.task_scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

    def reset(self):
        self.key_pressed = False
        self.recording_started = False
        self.recording_stopped = False

    def _on_press(self, key):
        # logging.info(key)
        if key == self.trigger_key:
            self.key_pressed = True
        return True

    def _on_release(self, key):
        # logging.info(key)
        if key == self.trigger_key:
            self.key_pressed = False
            # Close listener
            return False
        return True

    def record(self, fname):
        logging.info("Waiting for any key")
        self.reset()
        self.key_listener.start()
        recording_file = RecordingFile(
            fname=fname, mode='wb', channels=self.channels, rate=self.rate,
            frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer)
        def keychek_loop():
            if self.key_pressed and not self.recording_started:
                logging.info("Speak while you keep the key pressed.")
                recording_file.start_recording()
                self.recording_started = True
            elif not self.key_pressed and self.recording_started:
                recording_file.stop_recording()
                self.recording_stopped = True
            if not self.recording_stopped:
                self.task_scheduler.enter(delay=.1, priority=1, action=keychek_loop)
                self.task_scheduler.run()
        keychek_loop()


class RecordingFile(object):
    """"Type of object corresponding to a particular recording.

    See :py:class:KeyPressTriggeredRecorder for example usage.
    """
    def __init__(self, fname, mode, channels,
                 rate, frames_per_buffer):
        self.fname = fname
        self.mode = mode
        self.channels = channels
        self.rate = rate
        self.frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer
        self._pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.chosen_device_index = -1
        for x in range(0,self._pa.get_device_count()):
            info = self._pa.get_device_info_by_index(x)
            # logging.info(self._pa.get_device_info_by_index(x))
            if info["name"] == "pulse":
                self.chosen_device_index = info["index"]
                # logging.debug("Chosen index: %d", self.chosen_device_index)     
        self.wavefile = self._prepare_file(self.fname, self.mode)
        self._stream = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def record(self, duration):
        # Use a stream with no callback function in blocking mode
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                     channels=self.channels,
                                     rate=self.rate,
                                     input_device_index=self.chosen_device_index,
                                     input=True,
                                     frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer)
        for _ in range(int(self.rate / self.frames_per_buffer * duration)):
            audio = self._stream.read(self.frames_per_buffer)
            self.wavefile.writeframes(audio)
        return None

    def start_recording(self):
        # Use a stream with a callback in non-blocking mode
        # logging.info("Starting recording")
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                     channels=self.channels,
                                     rate=self.rate,
                                     input=True,
                                     frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer,
                                     stream_callback=self._get_callback())
        self._stream.start_stream()
        return self

    def stop_recording(self):
        self._stream.stop_stream()
        return self

    def _get_callback(self):
        def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            self.wavefile.writeframes(in_data)
            return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue
        return callback


    def close(self):
        self._stream.close()
        self._pa.terminate()
        self.wavefile.close()

    def _prepare_file(self, fname, mode='wb'):
        import os
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fname), exist_ok=True)
        wavefile = wave.open(fname, mode)
        wavefile.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wavefile.setsampwidth(self._pa.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wavefile.setframerate(self.rate)
        return wavefile

recorder.KeyPressTriggeredRecorder().record(FILEPATH)
```